# switch user leads to black screen

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, lightdm, switch-user

I'm on the latest 14.04 with `nvidia-331` drivers installed. Everything runs smoothly just when I try to switch user I get a black screen. Suspend and logout works with no problems.

Somehow I managed to make it work ones but after restart it was broken again and I'm not able to repeat the steps I made.

Seems it's an `nvidia` driver or `lightdm` problem since I can still connect by ssh even with black screen.

Any idea?

Comment: I have i915 driver and I have the same problem. My workaround is to press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Fn`,  *7<= n <=12*,  where *n* is a number decoding users that logged in after last reboot.  For the case of only one user it will be `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F7`.